# removing spaces from a string in C language

Tags: c, string, token

I can't figure out how to remove the spaces at the beginning of the sentence without using any libraries other than  stdio.h and stdlib.h.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char text[1000], result[1000];
   int c = 0, d = 0;

   printf("Enter some text\n");
   gets(text);

   while (text[c] != '\0') { // till the end of the string
      if (text[c] == ' ') {  
         int temp = c + 1;   
         if (text[temp] != '\0') {  
            while (text[temp] == ' ' && text[temp] != '\0') { 
               if (text[temp] == ' ') { 
                  c++;                  
               }  
               temp++;                  
            }
         }
      }
      result[d] = text[c];
      c++;               
      d++;
   }
   result[d] = '\0';

   printf("Text after removing blanks\n%s\n", result);

   return 0;
}
```

This piece of code removes all the extra spaces of a sentence.

**Example**:

*input:*    `"   this   is    my         program."`

*output:* `" this is my program."`

***EXPECTED OUTPUT:*** `"this is my program."`

this code leaves only one space where there were more spaces, but I want to remove all spaces at the beginning as well like in the expected output.

Comment: Are you trying to remove all spaces from a string? Or are you trying to remove all extra spaces between words? Can you provide the expected output for the "   this   is    my         program." input?

Comment: I updated it, I want to remove all the extra spaces between words, but also the space at the beginning of the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char text[1000], result[1000];
   int c = 0, d = 0;

   printf("Enter some text\n");
   gets(text);

   // no space at beginning
   while(text[c] ==' ') { c++; }
   while(text[c] != '\0'){
    result[d++] = text[c++]; //take non-space characters
    if(text[c]==' ') { result[d++] = text[c++]; } // take one space between words
    while(text[c]==' ') { c++; } // skip other spaces 
   }
   result[d] = '\0';

   printf("Text after removing blanks\n%s\n", result);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove all spaces at the beginning as well.

After getting the input, begin processing up to the first non-white-space.

```
// do not use gets()
fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin);
text[strcspn(text, "\n")] = '\0';  //lop off potential \n

char *ptext = text;
while (isspace((unsigned char) *ptext)) {
  ptext++;
} 

// now use ptext instead of text for rest of code.
```

Comment: `isspace()` is not declared in either of the permitted headers mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This function will process the input array as you need

```
void remove_white_space(char *source, char *result) {
    int i=0,key=0,k=0;
    while (source[i]!='\0') {
        if(source[i]==' ') {
            if (key== 0) {
                if(i==0) {
                    key=1;
                    ++i;
                } else {
                    key=1;
                result[k]=source[i];
                ++k;
                ++i;
                }
            } else
                ++i;
        } else {
            key=0;
            result[k]=source[i];
            ++k;
            ++i;
        }
    }
        result[k]='\0';
}
```